# Upgrade from Joomla 2.5 - 3.4 gives error

Tags: joomla, upgrade, joomla2.5

I get this error after doing upgrade from Joomla 2.5 to 3.4

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/rodoyo/public_html/administrator/components/com_installer/controller.php on line 37
```

I can find that line in my php config file but don't know what to change

Any ideas?

Comment: You should probably ask this on http://joomla.stackexchange.com/